# Html + javascript: weird different behaviour on computer and mobile devices with overflow divs

Tags: javascript, html

The issue belongs to a more complex thing but I've managed to make a minimal reproducible sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Fail on mobile</title>
      <!-- Babylon.js -->
      <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/babylon.js"></script>
      <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/gui/babylon.gui.min.js"></script>
      <style>
         html, body {
         overflow: hidden;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         }
         #renderCanvas {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         touch-action: none;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="canvasZone">
         <canvas touch-action="none" id="renderCanvas"></canvas>
      </div>
      <script>
         var canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas");
         
         var engine = null;
         var scene = null;
         var sceneToRender = null;
         var createDefaultEngine = function() 
         { 
             return new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true, { preserveDrawingBuffer: true, stencil: true,  disableWebGL2Support: false}); 
         };
         
         var createScene = function () 
         {
            // This creates a basic Babylon Scene object (non-mesh)
            var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
            
            // This creates and positions a free camera (non-mesh)
            var camera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera("camera1", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 5, -10), scene);
            
            var cornerDiv = document.createElement("div");
            cornerDiv.style.width = '100px';
            cornerDiv.style.height = '100px';
            cornerDiv.style.position = 'fixed';
            cornerDiv.style.top = '0';
            cornerDiv.style.right = '0';
            cornerDiv.style.justifyContent = "center";
            cornerDiv.style.background = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
            cornerDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/textures/icons/Delete.png')";
            cornerDiv.style.backgroundPosition = "center";
            cornerDiv.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
            canvasZone.appendChild(cornerDiv);         
            
            var movingDiv = document.createElement("div");
            movingDiv.style.width = '100px';
            movingDiv.style.height = '100px';
            movingDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
            movingDiv.style.top = '100px';
            movingDiv.style.left = '0';
            movingDiv.style.justifyContent = "center";
            movingDiv.style.background = "rgba(0, 128, 255, 1)";
            movingDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/textures/icons/Play.png')";
            movingDiv.style.backgroundPosition = "center";
            movingDiv.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
            canvasZone.appendChild(movingDiv);
            
            var xPos = canvasZone.offsetLeft - 100;
            scene.onAfterRenderObservable.add(() =>
            {
                xPos+=15;
                if(xPos > canvasZone.offsetLeft + canvasZone.offsetWidth + 200)
                    xPos = (canvasZone.offsetLeft -100);
                movingDiv.style.left = xPos+'px';
            });
            
            return scene;
         };

         window.initFunction = async function() {            
            var asyncEngineCreation = async function() {
                try {
                return createDefaultEngine();
                } catch(e) {
                return createDefaultEngine();
                }
            }

            window.engine = await asyncEngineCreation();
            if (!engine) throw 'engine should not be null.';
            window.scene = createScene();
         };

         initFunction().then(() => {sceneToRender = scene        
             engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
                 if (sceneToRender && sceneToRender.activeCamera) {
                     sceneToRender.render();
                 }
             });
         });
         
         // Resize
         window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
             engine.resize();
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

It is just a div that is moved over another parent div and it works ok on computers even if it overflows its size, but it has a weird behavior on mobile devices since it seems to make the canvas bigger.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line into your `<head> ... </head>` should help

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, it introduces a new issue in the mobile devices: the blue one "drags" the red one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Veter who point me in the right direction

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1>
```

was the key!